# asp.net/javascript creating cookies, advantages creating client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I need to create a cookie, this isn't a session cookie, but a cookie with an expiry date.

Are there any advantages creating the cookie via server side code or via javascript?

Actually my server side is a asp.net rest service so probably this isn't a good idea?

Are there any advantages or disadvantages in using either method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any alternatives creating the cookie via server side code or via javascript?

No.

> Actually my server side is a asp.net rest service so probably this isn't a good idea?

REST services usually do not deal or know about cookies. They could but it's not a common practice. REST services are using different techniques of authentication, such as sending some value in the `Authorization` HTTP request header.

> Are there any advantages or disadvantages in using either method?

It would really depend on your scenario and what kind of information you are attempting to store. For example with a server side script you could create an [`HttpOnly cookie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) which is not accessible by client scripts, only by server side scripts. In any case you should not be storing sensitive information in cookies (unless encrypted and signed) because the client could easily tamper with the value and forge an HTTP request that sends any cookie value he wants.

Comment: I was hoping to store a token that was received by my backend, good idea to use javascript to the write the cookie then?

Comment: And not using the REST api?